# Wordpress widget type functionality in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been working with django over past couple of months. It seems that if I need some new value in a template, the only way to accomplish that is to pass it through the view function directly or an object that can be somehow used to retrieve that information.

What if I want to "PULL" information from the template? Consider the following scenario. I have a template "template1" associated with Application1. Suppose in one column of this template, I want to import information from second application "Application2". Currently the only way I know is to use the Application1's view functions to pull that info from Application2. For every new application I need to change my Application1's view function. So in case I want to keep adding information from different applications(2,3,4 etc), I would need to keep on changing the view function of Application1. This could get cumbersome.

So what I want is something like Wordpress's widget function or Joomla's module type functionality. Simple plug and play, that can "pull" the information from different sources(apps). Does django have something of this sort built-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you have encountered one of the fundamental differences between Django (and most Python templating frameworks) and WordPress (and most PHP frameworks). PHP has a *huge* global name space that can be accessed from pretty much any place in the page creation process. Python, on the other hand, does not. Many of us consider this to be a Good Thing®.

However, there are times when you wish you had a few more globals for use in your templates. To accomplish this, what you want is a [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). This is a routine that returns a dict that is automatically included whenever you use `RequestContext()` to build your call to your template.

You may also want to look at [{% expr ... %}](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/). It allows you to break out of the "chains" of the deliberately weak Django templating engine.

Comment: So basically you mean I can add new view functions to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and those dict values will be delivered to me in Request?

Comment: In a word, yes. One note of caution: if any of these values are "expensive" (whatever that means) then you will pay that cost for every page load that uses RequestContext(). I have a couple of these and I use a simple cache function to keep from hitting the DB on every page load.